Expanding variable group resource data: failed to get Azure key value.Failed to query service connection API

`Error: Expanding variable group resource data: Failed to get the
Azure Key value. Error: ( code: unused, messge: Failed to query
service connection API:
'https://ecn-dev-we-hub-kv.vault.azure.net/secrets?api-version=2016-10-01'.
Error Message: 'An error occurred while sending the request.' ) │ │
with
module.azuredevops.azuredevops_variable_group.example_keyvault_link, │
on azuredevops\main.tf line 38, in resource
"azuredevops_variable_group" "example_keyvault_link": │   38: resource
"azuredevops_variable_group" "example_keyvault_link" {

I am trying to create variable group and link keyvaults secrets as variables to variable group. Providing my code below
provider "azuredevops" {
org_service_url = var.org_service_url
personal_access_token = var.personal_access_token
}
data "azuredevops_project" "project" {
name = var.project_name
}

data "azuredevops_serviceendpoint_azurerm" "serviceendpoint" {
project_id            = data.azuredevops_project.project.id
service_endpoint_name = "testing"
}

resource "azuredevops_variable_group" "example" {
project_id   = data.azuredevops_project.project.id
name         = var.variablegroup_name
description  = "Example Variable Group Description"
allow_access = true
depends_on = [
data.azuredevops_serviceendpoint_azurerm.serviceendpoint
]
key_vault {
name                = "${var.prefix}-kv"
service_endpoint_id = data.azuredevops_serviceendpoint_azurerm.serviceendpoint.id
}
variable {
name = "storageAccountKey"
}

variable {
name = "localAdminSecret"
}
}

the problem is when i comment out keyvault part and push changes and run pipeline varibale group gets created and again i have to uncomment the keyvault part and push changes and run pipeline in order to link keyvault secrets to variable group . But when i am trying to achieve creating variable group and linking its secret to variable as a whole code without commenting keyvault part then I am facing this error .
can someone help me resolve the issue

Try adding depends_on block to ensure the Azure Key Vault is fully provisioned before linking it in the variable group @Deepika refer: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/depends_on

Hi Vinay, did you mean adding
depends_on = [
data.azuredevops_serviceendpoint_azurerm.serviceendpoint
]
I have tried this as well, but still same error persists.
and i can't add depends on within inline code. could you please help me where to add the dependencies

Do you have any firewall or proxy applied to your Azure Key Vault? @Deepika

Try using a null_resource with local-exec to wait for Key Vault readiness, and set depends_on in azuredevops_variable_group to depend on this null_resource @Deepika

@BrightRan-MSFT -- No firewall or proxy is applied to keyvault in my case

@Deepika, If you manually create the variable group and link the Azure Key Vault secrets using the same service endpoint on the web UI of Azure DevOps, does it work fine? Try this on the same machine where you execute the Terraform deployment.

@BrightRan-MSFT -- It works with manual creation . I have observed that resource keyvault creation , azurerm_key_vault_secret creation is taking time , before this keyvault module resources are created , azuredevops module starts creating variable group resource, due to which I am getting this error .

@Deepika, So, you are try to use the Terraform to first create the Azure Key Vault and secrets, then use Terraform to create the variable group and link the Key Vault secrets. Right? If so, please provide the detailed Terraform files (.tf) and pipeline YAML files to show hwo to configure the resources and the pipeline.

@Deepika, You mentioned "I have observed that resource keyvault creation , azurerm_key_vault_secret creation is taking time , before this keyvault module resources are created , azuredevops module starts creating variable group resource, due to which I am getting this error .". Do you mean that you defined the creation of Azure Key Vault, Key Vault secret and variable group within the same Terraform files (.tf) instead of in two files? If so, try to split them into two file, one is creating the Azure Key Vault and Key Vault secret, another is creating variable group.

@Deepika, You can defined two jobs in your pipeline: The first one is running the Terraform to create/update the Azure Key Vault and Key Vault secret, and the second is creating variable group. You can set the second job only runs when the first one is completed successfully.

@VinayB & Bright Ran-MSFT - Thank you !!
My issue resolved with this suggestion "null_resource with local-exec to wait for Key Vault readiness, and set depends_on in azuredevops_variable_group to depend on this null_resource "

Glad to know it works you @Deepika Posting it as solution so that community people  who might came across similar issue will have ready to use solution

@Deepika, Glad that the problem can be resolved. Maybe, you can post an answer to show more details about how you fix the issue. It could be also helpful for other people who are looking for a solution of the similar issues.

solution to my error was using a null_resource with local-exec to wait for Key Vault readiness, and set depends_on in azuredevops_variable_group to depend on this null_resource .
In my case , we are using two different modules one for keyvault creation & and another module for variable group creation module name azuredevops.
I have added null resource in keyvault module
keyvault/main.tf 

data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "rg-management" {
  name = local.resource_group_management
}

data "azurerm_storage_account" "sg" {
  name                = var.initstorageccount
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg-management.name
}

# Key Vault Resource
resource "azurerm_key_vault" "example" {
  name                        = "${var.prefix}-kv5"  # Change the name for the new Key Vault
  location                    = var.location
  resource_group_name         = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg-management.name
  enabled_for_disk_encryption = true
  tenant_id                   = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  soft_delete_retention_days  = 90
  purge_protection_enabled    = true
  sku_name                    = "standard"

  access_policy {
    tenant_id       = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
    object_id       = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id
    secret_permissions = [
      "Set",
      "Get",
      "List",
      "Delete",
      "Backup",
      "Purge",
      "Recover", 
      "Restore"
    ]
    storage_permissions = [
      "Set",
      "Get",
      "List",
      "Delete"
    ]
  }
  access_policy {
    tenant_id       = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
    object_id       = var.aad_object_id # Replace with your Azure Active Directory(AAD) object ID
    secret_permissions = ["Set", "Get", "List"]
    storage_permissions = ["Set", "Get", "List"]
  }
}

# add secrets to the new Key Vault
resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "storage_account_key" {
  name         = "storageAccountKey"
  value        = data.azurerm_storage_account.sg.primary_access_key
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.example.id
}

resource "random_password" "password" {
  length = 12
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "localadminsecret" {
  name         = "localAdminSecret"
  value        = random_password.password.result
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.example.id
}


resource "null_resource" "wait_for_key_vault" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "echo 'Waiting for Key Vault readiness' && sleep 60"  # Adjust the sleep duration as needed
  }
  triggers = {
    key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.example.id
  }
}

output it's values in keyvault/output.tf 

keyvault/output.tf



  output "key_vault_ready" {
      value = null_resource.wait_for_key_vault.id
    }
    output "key_vault_id" {
      value = azurerm_key_vault.example.id
    }

adding null resource dependency in azuredevops module while creating variable group resource

azuredevops/main.tf 

provider "azuredevops" {
  org_service_url = var.org_service_url
  personal_access_token = var.personal_access_token
}


data "azuredevops_project" "project" {
  name = var.project_name 
}

data "azuredevops_serviceendpoint_azurerm" "serviceendpoint" {
  project_id            = data.azuredevops_project.project.id
  service_endpoint_name = var.service_endpoint_name
}



resource "azuredevops_variable_group" "example" {
  project_id   = data.azuredevops_project.project.id
  name         = var.variablegroup_name
  description  = "Example Variable Group Description"
  allow_access = true
  depends_on = [ data.azuredevops_serviceendpoint_azurerm.serviceendpoint, 
  var.key_vault_ready ]
  
  key_vault {
    name                = "${var.prefix}-kv5"
    service_endpoint_id = data.azuredevops_serviceendpoint_azurerm.serviceendpoint.id
  }

  variable {
    name = "storageAccountKey"
  }

  variable {
    name = "localAdminSecret"  
    }
}

Pass the key_vault_ready output in the Root main.tf:

module "keyvault" {
    source = "./keyvault"
    prefix                =var.prefix
    location              =var.location
    initstorageccount       = var.initstorageccount
    resourceGroupStorage   =var.resourceGroupStorage
    aad_object_id = var.aad_object_id
    }
    
    # # Module for keyvault
    module "azuredevops" {
    source = "./azuredevops"
    prefix                =var.prefix
    org_service_url = var.org_service_url
    project_name = var.project_name
    variablegroup_name = var.variablegroup_name
    personal_access_token = var.personal_access_token
    service_endpoint_name = var.service_endpoint_name
    # service_endpoint_id = var.service_endpoint_id
    key_vault_id=module.keyvault.key_vault_id
    key_vault_ready = module.keyvault.key_vault_ready
    
    }

pipeline execution

If the solution shared in this answer can work for you, you can accept is by yourself. It might also can help other people who have the similar issues. @Deepika

You can use separate Terraform files (.tf) to define the creation of Azure Key Vault (include the Key Vault secret) and variable group.
And then define two jobs in your pipeline, the first one is running Terraform to create the Azure Key Vault and Key Vault secret, and the second is creating the variable group. You can set the second job dependsOn the first job so that it only runs when the first one is completed successfully.
See below example as reference:
The pipeline main YAML.
# azure-pipelines.yml

variables:
  ArmConnection: 'xxxx'
  ResourceGroup: 'xxxx'
  StorageAccount: 'xxxx'
  BlobContainer: 'xxxx'
  AzKeyVault: 'BrightRanKV06'
  AdoOrgName: 'xxxx'
  VarGroupName: 'MySecretVarGroup'

jobs:
- job: AzKV
  displayName: 'Create Azure Key Vault'
  steps:
  - template: templates/steps-create-AzKeyVault.yml
    parameters:
      ArmConnection: $(ArmConnection)
      ResourceGroup: $(ResourceGroup)
      StorageAccount: $(StorageAccount)
      BlobContainer: $(BlobContainer)
      KeyVaultName: $(AzKeyVault)

- job: VarGroup
  displayName: 'Create Variable Group'
  dependsOn: AzKV
  steps:
  - template: templates/steps-create-ado-vargroup.yml
    parameters:
      AdoOrgName: $(AdoOrgName)
      ArmConnection: $(ArmConnection)
      VarGroupName: $(VarGroupName)
      AzKeyVault: $(AzKeyVault)


The files for creation of Azure Key Vault and Key Vault secret.


The file templates/steps-create-AzKeyVault.yml

parameters:
- name: ArmConnection
  type: string
- name: ResourceGroup
  type: string
- name: StorageAccount
  type: string
- name: BlobContainer
  type: string
- name: KeyVaultName
  type: string

steps:
- task: TerraformInstaller@1
  displayName: 'Install Terraform'

- task: TerraformTaskV4@4
  displayName: 'Terraform init'
  inputs:
    provider: 'azurerm'
    command: 'init'
    workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/AzKeyVault'
    backendAzureRmUseEntraIdForAuthentication: true
    backendServiceArm: ${{ parameters.ArmConnection }}
    backendAzureRmResourceGroupName: ${{ parameters.ResourceGroup }}
    backendAzureRmStorageAccountName: ${{ parameters.StorageAccount }}
    backendAzureRmContainerName: ${{ parameters.BlobContainer }}
    backendAzureRmKey: 'AzKeyVault/${{ parameters.KeyVaultName }}.tfstate'

- task: TerraformTaskV4@4
  displayName: 'Terraform plan'
  inputs:
    provider: 'azurerm'
    command: 'plan'
    workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/AzKeyVault'
    commandOptions: > 
      -out=main.tfplan
      -var="resourcegroup_name=${{ parameters.ResourceGroup }}"
      -var="keyvault_name=${{ parameters.KeyVaultName }}"
    environmentServiceNameAzureRM: ${{ parameters.ArmConnection }}

- task: TerraformTaskV4@4
  displayName: 'Terraform apply'
  inputs:
    provider: 'azurerm'
    command: 'apply'
    workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/AzKeyVault'
    commandOptions: main.tfplan
    environmentServiceNameAzureRM: ${{ parameters.ArmConnection }}

- task: TerraformTaskV4@4
  displayName: 'Terraform output'
  inputs:
    provider: 'azurerm'
    command: 'output'
    workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/AzKeyVault'
    environmentServiceNameAzureRM: ${{ parameters.ArmConnection }}


The file AzKeyVault/providers.tf

terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = ">=4.6.0"
    }
  }

  backend "azurerm" {}
}

provider "azurerm" {
  use_oidc = true
  features {
      key_vault {
          purge_soft_delete_on_destroy    = true
          recover_soft_deleted_key_vaults = true
      }
  }
}


The file AzKeyVault/main.tf

data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "my_resourcegroup" {
  name = var.resourcegroup_name
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault" "my_keyvault" {
    name                        = var.keyvault_name
    resource_group_name         = data.azurerm_resource_group.my_resourcegroup.name
    location                    = data.azurerm_resource_group.my_resourcegroup.location
    sku_name                    = var.keyvault_sku
    tenant_id                   = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
    soft_delete_retention_days  = 7
    purge_protection_enabled    = false

    access_policy {
        tenant_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
        object_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id

        secret_permissions = [
            "Set",
            "Get",
            "List",
            "Delete",
            "Purge",
            "Recover"
        ]
    }
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "secret1" {
    name         = "secVar01"
    value        = "sv111"
    key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.my_keyvault.id

    depends_on = [azurerm_key_vault.my_keyvault]
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "secret2" {
    name         = "secVar02"
    value        = "sv222"
    key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.my_keyvault.id

    depends_on = [azurerm_key_vault.my_keyvault]
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "secret3" {
    name         = "secVar03"
    value        = "sv333"
    key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.my_keyvault.id

    depends_on = [azurerm_key_vault.my_keyvault]
}


The files for creation of variable group.


The file templates/steps-create-ado-vargroup.yml

parameters:
- name: AdoOrgName
  type: string
- name: ArmConnection
  type: string
- name: VarGroupName
  type: string
- name: AzKeyVault
  type: string

steps:
- task: TerraformInstaller@1
  displayName: 'Install Terraform'

- task: Bash@3
  displayName: 'Terraform init'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: terraform init
    workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/ADO_VarGroup'

# The PAT requires the following scopes:
#   - Build (Read & execute);              - Project and Team (Read);
#   - Service Connections (Read & query);  - Token Administration (Read & manage);
#   - Tokens (Read & manage);              - Variable Groups (Read, create, & manage);
#   - Work Items (Read)
- task: Bash@3
  displayName: 'Terraform plan'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      terraform plan \
      -out=main.tfplan \
      -var=ado_org_url=https://dev.azure.com/${{ parameters.AdoOrgName }} \
      -var=ado_access_token=$MY_ADO_PAT \
      -var=project_name=$(System.TeamProject) \
      -var=endpoint_name=${{ parameters.ArmConnection }} \
      -var=vargroup_name=${{ parameters.VarGroupName }} \
      -var=keyvault_name=${{ parameters.AzKeyVault }}
    workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/ADO_VarGroup'
  env:
    MY_ADO_PAT: $(myPAT)

- task: Bash@3
  displayName: 'Terraform apply'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: terraform apply -auto-approve main.tfplan
    workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/ADO_VarGroup'

- task: Bash@3
  displayName: 'Terraform output'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: terraform output -json
    workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/ADO_VarGroup'


The file ADO_VarGroup/providers.tf

terraform {
  required_providers {
    azuredevops = {
      source  = "microsoft/azuredevops"
      version = ">=1.4.0"
    }
  }

  backend "local" {
    path = "tfbackend/terraform.tfstate"
  }
}

provider "azuredevops" {
  org_service_url = var.ado_org_url
  personal_access_token = var.ado_access_token
}


The file ADO_VarGroup/main.tf

data "azuredevops_project" "my_project" {
  name = var.project_name
}

data "azuredevops_serviceendpoint_azurerm" "my_endpoint" {
  project_id            = data.azuredevops_project.my_project.id
  service_endpoint_name = var.endpoint_name
}

resource "azuredevops_variable_group" "my_vargroup" {
  project_id   = data.azuredevops_project.my_project.id
  name         = var.vargroup_name
  description  = var.vargroup_description
  allow_access = true

  key_vault {
    name                = var.keyvault_name
    service_endpoint_id = data.azuredevops_serviceendpoint_azurerm.my_endpoint.id
  }

  variable {
    name = "secVar01"
  }

  variable {
    name = "secVar02"
  }
}


The result after running the pipeline.



